# How do i set criteria for default value in multivalued field

Tags: ms-access

I'm not an IT expert, i'm a hobbyist trying to create an access db for my hospital lab. The lab tests db i'm trying to create has a fields like microbiology, serology, parasite. The field named "parasite" is a multivalued field that can have more than one value because a person can have (infected with) multiple parasites at a time. If microbiology and/or serology test is done and   parasite is not done for a given patient i want the field parasites to be "NA" to avoid the null. for this i've made the default value in the table property "NA". But even when i enter the value in the parasite field the NA selection is there, so i want an expression that excludes NA when i enter value in parasite field and keep NA when no value is entered.
Thanks

Comment: I strongly advise NOT using a multivalued field. It may seem appropriate to a novice, but down the road it will present more problems than it is worth. Instead use a child table with a subform. There has been ample written on the subject, so I won't repeat here. You can easily bingoogle it.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're specifying the default value is correct, but the solution will become complicated for your intended purposes. By specifying the `NA` as the default value in the multivalued field, that option is already being selected. You would need to manually deselect the option.

I would advise allowing the null value and use the `Nz` function to fix your data display requirements.

So if you have a query or report displaying the entered data, you can use:
In a report or form control:

`= Nz([Parasite].[Value], "N/A")`

In a query:

`ParasiteFormatted: Nz([Parasite].[Value], "N/A")`

The `Nz` function will replace Null values with the value specified in the second parameter of the function, in this case, `N/A`. And use the actual value of the field if it's not null.

See these two links for more info:

1. https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php
2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

Comment: I tried to use the expression in query, but i got an error message. The multivalued field "[parasite]" is not valid in the expression 'Nz([parasite], "NA"). What other options do i have?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to add `.Value` to the field name for a multivalued field in a query like `[Parasite].[Value]` instead of just `[Parasite]`